# Rails association doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I am having a weird issue that I can't figure out.

It is very basic rails programming : I want to create an association between a user model and a goal model.

**goal.rb**

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :goals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :records
  has_many :orders
end
```

When I am making the association from the console, it is working well, lets say :

```
$ goal = Goal.first
$ goal.user_id = 1
$ goal.save 
$ goal.inspect 


#<Goal id: 1, description: "loremipsum", created_at: "2016-11-26 12:39:34", updated_at: "2016-11-26 12:43:41", name: "ipsumlorem", user_id: 1>
```

But then, when I am creating a goal from my views, the association is not made, and the user_id of the goal user_id remain : nil.

Any ideas ?

EDIT AS REQUIRED :

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@goal) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control"  %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

goal_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @users = User.all
    @goal = current_user.goals.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @goal = Goal.new(goal_params)
    @goal.save
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Objectif sauvegardé"  
  end
```

Comment: Can you show your view and your controller code instead as the question is more so regarding a problem with view and controller.

Comment: @vee done - updated with the views code

Comment: What happens if you do `@goal = current_user.goals.build(goal_params)` in your `create` action? You're doing `Goal.new(goal_params)` where `goal_params` does not have a `user_id` set because you don't have it supplied to `goal_params` in any way.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create
  # Here!!!!
  @goal = current_user.goals.new(goal_params)
  @goal.save
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Objectif sauvegardé"  
end
```